# What is the correct way to properly get an image from the gallery on Android 10 without using requestLegacyExternalStorage?

Tags: android, kotlin, scoped-storage

I have been trying to get an image from the gallery so I can upload it. However, every time I get a "File not Found" exception. All the SO questions I have found are seriously outdated suggesting to use the  `requestLegacyExternalStorage` which is only a temp fix.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#direct-file-paths), we are supposed to use a content resolver -- but that crashes.

I show the picker via:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
intent.data = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
intent.type = "image/*"
```

and in the fragments `onActivityResult`

```
   data.data?.let { uri ->
         Log.d(TAG, uri.toString())
         requireContext().contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).use { stream ->
             //this is where the crash happens
         }
    }
```

The manifest has:

```
 < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

 < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

I can see the URI as:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F62/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/1163354121
```

What is the correct way to do this?

The stack trace:

```
2021-12-06 13:14:37.676 4304-4304/net.mycompany.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.mycompany.myapp, PID: 4304
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1935067080, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content:xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F63/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/1254790127} }} to activity {net.mycompany.myapp/net.mycompany.myapp.ui.activities.JobDetailsActivity}: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Failed to validate: content://media/external/images/media/63
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4418)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4460)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1830)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Failed to validate: content://media/external/images/media/63
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:698)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1471)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1308)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1028)
        at net.mycompany.myapp.ui.fragments.jobdetails.PhotosFragment.onActivityResult(PhotosFragment.kt:225)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2905)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$9.onActivityResult(FragmentManager.java:2885)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.doDispatch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:392)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(ActivityResultRegistry.java:351)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onActivityResult(ComponentActivity.java:647)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4460) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1830) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6831) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: So what is the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: `this is where the crash happens` -- what is the crash? "What is the correct way to do this?" -- what you have seems reasonable.

Comment: @CommonsWare i've added the Stack Trace to the question

Comment: I am having difficulty tracking down the `Failed to validate` message in the AOSP. What device make and model are you testing on?

Comment: @CommonsWare a Kyrocera E6910

Comment: Have you tried on anything else, such as an Android SDK emulator?

Comment: @CommonsWare a physical Pixel 3XL - it works on that device.

Comment: Then perhaps Kyocera made a mistake somewhere. You might consider adding `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` to  your `Intent` to see if that changes anything. If you get back a `Uri` that does not work with `openInputStream()`, then Kyocera broke the SDK contract.